# How do you show or hide a button based on user action?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Well I have a web page asp.net(page1.aspx) amm user can choose two options A/B
if user chooses a when he is in page2.aspx i want a javascript was execute

```
function(receive parameter)
{
}
```

But if he chose option B function never will be executed.

I want to do, if user chooses A will see a asp button, but if he choose option b he
is not going to be the button

Comment: Please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: user is in page1.aspx he is going to have 2 options, when he press first option he will be redirected to page2.aspx watching in this (page2) a button but he user in page1.aspx he chose secund option he will be redirected to page2.aspx too but he is not going to be the button

Comment: is this a poem taken from engrish.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a querystring parameter...

Page1

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Redirect("~/page2.aspx?showButton=true", true);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Redirect("~/page2.aspx?showButton=false", true);
}
```

Page2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    someButton.Visible = (Request[@"showButton"] == @"true");
}
```

The example isn't that elegant, but should get you started on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
Page 1  - Button 1 (to Page 2 with Button on page 2)
          Button 2 (to Page 2 without Button on Page 2)

Page 2
```

You are using ASP.Net so use the 'Code Behind' and server side controls. The most simplest concept would be to use GET variables, aka QueryStrings.

**Create 2 Buttons on Page 1.**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1Click" 
        Text="Button 1" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2Click" 
        Text="Button 2" />
```

**Add actions to those buttons (Page 1)**

```
 protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?Option=1",true);
    }

    protected void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx?Option=2",true);
    }
```

**On Page 2 Load event**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Option"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Option"] == "1")
            {
                Response.Write("Option 1");
            }
            else if (Request.QueryString["Option"] == "2")
            {
                Response.Write("Option 2");
            }

        }
    }
```